# natbib \citep*{} still only prints first author

Tags: natbib

I have some issues with citations in my thesis. I use the `natbib` package and the `apalike` bibliography style. When I cite articles with 1 or 2 authors, everything works just fine. But when I have 3 authors, things break down. Only the first author is printed followed by et al., also when I change `\citep{}` to `\citep*{}`

```
\documentclass[english,11pt]{book} 
\usepackage{natbib}

\title{Brief Article}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\citep{AlJarrah2015}.


\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{mwebib} 

\end{document}
```

my `.bib` file looks as follows:

```
@article{AlJarrah2015,
doi = {10.1016/j.bdr.2015.04.001},
year = 2015,
month = {sep},
publisher = {Elsevier {BV}},
volume = {2},
number = {3},
pages = {87--93},
author = {Omar Y. Al-Jarrah and Paul D. Yoo and Sami Muhaidat and George K. 
Karagiannidis and Kamal Taha},
title = {Efficient Machine Learning for Big Data: A Review},
journal = {Big Data Research}
}
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong or why this isn't working. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: (1) Welcome, (2) this is not really a LaTeX issue, but rather an issue with the `apalike` style not being 100% compatible with `natbib`, try using `plainnat` and you will see the difference.  Also see the generated `.bbl` files in both cases, the `apalike` one does not give the same amount of info.

Comment: @Mico see the generated `.bbl` for `apalike` it will never work with that `.bst`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @daleif demonstrates in his answer, the `apalike` bibliography style simply isn't set up properly to let you generate citation callouts that state all authors of entries that feature at least three authors.

Rather than hack the ancient `apalike` bibliography style -- I believe it's OK to call it ancient, given that it hasn't been changed meaningfully since the mid-1980s -- you may want to consider using the much more up-to-date `apacite` bibliography style, along with the `apacite` citation management package; specify the option `natbibapa` if you want to keep using `\citet` and `\citep`.

Your MWE would become:

```
\documentclass[11pt,english]{book}
\usepackage{url,babel}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}

\begin{document}
\citet{AlJarrah2015}
\bibliography{mwebib}
\end{document}
```

The *first* citation call-out generated by `\citet{AlJarrah2015}` would like this:

> Al-Jarrah, Yoo, Muhaidat, Karagiannidis, and Taha (2015)

In keeping with APA citation conventions, second and further citation call-outs to this entry would be formatted as

> Al-Jarrah et al. (2015)

Answer (score 1):

This is basically a problem with the `apalike` bibtex style. It is not 100% compatible with `natbib`, it does not provide the information ndded for say `\citep*` to work. Here is a sniplet from the generated `.bbl` file for `apalike`:

```
\bibitem[Al-Jarrah et~al., 2015]{AlJarrah2015}
```

Here is the corresponding one for `plainnat` (which is 100% compatible with `natbib`):

```
\bibitem[Al-Jarrah et~al.(2015)Al-Jarrah, Yoo, Muhaidat, 
  Karagiannidis, and Taha]{AlJarrah2015}
```